# lodash - sort result of _.groupBy before creating an array with it

Tags: angular, sorting, underscore.js, lodash

I'm using lodash's groupBy to group objects by a number value which can be 1 - 10. Let's call the property "sort"

the result of the groupBy looks like

```
{
    1:[{sort:1,...}, ...],
    2:[{sort:2,...}], ...].
    ...
}
```

Next I use Object.values(result) to convert it back into a 2 dimensional array for displaying it in angular with a double ngFor.

The thing is that I can't be certain (can I?) that the order of the object well be in order. Does the groupBy creates the keys in first-fit order?

So in case the result looks like

```
{
    3:[...],
    1:[...],
    2:[...],
    ...
}
```

How presort the _groupBy result before pushing it to an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to have a hard time trusting the iteration order of JavaScript objects as well. I suggest you remove the uncertainty by using lodash's [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy) function for collections.

If I've interpreted your question correctly, applying `sortBy` to your `result` object (using the [`_.property` iteratee shorthand](https://lodash.com/docs#map)) should give you the 2D array structure you're looking for:

```
this.target_data = _.sortyBy(result, 'sort');
```

`this.target_data` becomes a 2D array: the first row is a list of objects of `sort = 1`, the next is a list of objects of `sort = 2`, etc.

Please see [this](https://repl.it/repls/ZanyPuzzlingDictionary) quick demo.

Answer (score 0):

This is very clearly defined in the documentation for the [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy) method:

> Creates an object composed of keys generated from the results of running each element of collection thru iteratee. **The order of grouped values is determined by the order they occur in collection**. The corresponding value of each key is an array of elements responsible for generating the key. The iteratee is invoked with one argument: (value).

If you would like to order these you would need to `_.orderBy` / `_.sortBy` before the `_.groupBy`

Answer (score 0):

Since your keys are numbers, [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Examples) will create an array with the values sorted by the original keys numeric values.

```js
const data = {
    3:3,
    1:1,
    2:2,
};

const result = Object.values(data);

console.log(result);
```